# How to display POST request on the website with node.js

Tags: node.js, post, server

I've needed a simple server so I've made one with some help from the internet because I don't have a lot of knowledge about nodejs. So it work's fine. When I access it through the http://localhost:8080 it shows the simple html site and when it's running in the terminal window and there is POST http request it will be displayed (`console.log('lat: ' + formatted[0].latitude + ' lng: ' + formatted[0].longitude + ' time: ' + formattedDate);`). But is it possible to display the incoming message on the website?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var page = fs.readFileSync('./page.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if(req.method === "GET"){
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type' : 'text/html'
        });
        res.end(page);
    } else if (req.method === "POST") {
          var reqBody = "";
    //when user sends data it's being executed (in progress)
    req.on('data', function (incomingData) {
        reqBody += incomingData;
    });

    //when data is received
    req.on('end', function () {
        //console.log('POST REQ: ' + reqBody);    
        var formatted = JSON.parse(reqBody);
        var formattedDate = new Date(formatted[0].time);
        //console.log('downloaded: ' + reqBody);
        console.log('lat: ' + formatted[0].latitude + ' lng: ' + formatted[0].longitude + ' time: ' + formattedDate);
        res.end('<p>POST</p>');
    });
    }


}).listen(8080);
```

I was trying to display anything (`res.end('<p>POST</p>');`) when the request appears but it didn't work.

Comment: Try storing the result in variable and posting that.

Comment: `var postData = 'lat: ' + formatted[0].latitude + ' lng: ' + formatted[0].longitude + ' time: ' + formattedDate
        console.log(postData);
        res.end(postData);` How can I post it on the website? Something like this doesn't work for the website but works for the terminal.

Comment: ``res.end`` sends any data back to the browser. Why is it not working for you?

Comment: So what's wrong with this code? I've res.end and it doesn't display anything. There is still html page.

Comment: You will have to send a post request to the server for the post part of your code to be executed .  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp.  Easiest way to do that is to create an html form. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Even when I want raw message?